# How to use more than 8 boolean operators in ScienceDirect advanced search?

Tags: literature-search, elsevier

The advanced search in the ScienceDirect database seems to be limited to 8 boolean operators at max. This number of operators might not be sufficient, especially when applying a search string within a systematic literature review that is valid for other databases, e.g., ACM DL or IEEE Xplore DL which are capable of accepting search strings holding more boolean operators.

What are strategies to apply a search string with more than 8 boolean operators to the ScienceDirect database?

Comment: Please post the exact error message you received so that people might be able to help you.

Comment: @Tripartio "Use fewer boolean connectors (max 8 per field)"

Comment: Split it into two (or more) separate queries and combine the results.

Comment: Talk to a research librarian at your institution.

Comment: If the error message explicitly says that the system only supports max 8 per field, then you should follow the advice of @Louic.

Comment: @Louic is there any tool to find the distinct results from the search results obtained from multiple queries?

Comment: A reference manager?